# MySQL COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN DISTINCT Column)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case, distinct

My query:

```
COUNT(
    CASE WHEN YEAR(FieldValue) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(FieldValue) = MONTH(CURDATE())
    THEN 1
    END
) AS mtd
```

I want something like:

```
COUNT(
    CASE WHEN YEAR(FieldValue) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(FieldValue) = MONTH(CURDATE())
    THEN DISTINCT ColumnID
    END
) AS mtd
```

This gives an error. I can not use **GROUP BY**. If I add DISTINCT before CASE it does not work either it treats FieldValue column as DISTINCT but I want it to count ColumnID as distinct.

Please help

Comment: Show the entire query. Have you tried adding the `DISTINCT` right before the actual case i.e: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ...)`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this

```
  COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN YEAR(FieldValue) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(FieldValue) = MONTH(CURDATE())
    THEN ColumnID 
    END )

  ) AS mtd
```

Comment: this will count unique ColumnIDs and count them yes.

Comment: how about multiple case statements ?

Comment: anyway to have more than 1 column in the DISTINCT ? like THEN ColumnID, AnotherID.
It gives a parse exception because of the comma